# Reasons behind distributing files into many folders instead of a single folder

Tags: java, file, directory

I'm reviewing the code of a legacy application written in Java, a content delivery server. They have a file repository where the files contained are all named after an MD5 Hash Hex of their content.

```
7ABC1FBF6109EAB64DF6682158317181.dat
```

There are thousands of these files. The repository file structure is as follows:

```
C:/base/resources/repository/{First two digits of hex MD5 hash}/{MD5 hash hex}.dat
```

ex:

```
C:/base/resources/repository/7A/7ABC1FBF6109EAB64DF6682158317181.dat
```

Are there any reasons that would validate doing this, assuming there is no business logic that requires it (I'm telling you there isn't). The application gets requests for files and responds with the content in the file, mapped by the hash.

I really can't think of anything.

The application was running on a Linux machine, I don't know which distribution or what file system they were using.

Comment: That's a question of performance. Listing thousands of files in a directory can become slow, so it is common to create a sub-directory arborescence to obtain directories of moderate size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some file system calls become very slow when a single directory contains a huge number of files, especially on Windows. And it's also harder to administer them because simply listing their content is too slow and returns too many entries.

Comment: This files would never be managed manually. They're long lived temp files.

Comment: The files must be read, written, and found, manually or not. This becomes slow when the directory is huge.

Answer (score 1):

By the properties of a hash

```
{First two digits of hex MD5 hash}/{MD5 hash hex}.dat
```

is meaningless.  In any filesystem directories should logically group things together, but by definition there is no logical relation between two hashed items that share the same prefix.  My guess is someone was sick of seeing too many files in a directory at once, so this is likely related to performance.

Comment: It is, indeed, due to performance. It doesn't have much to do with personal dislikes.

Answer (score 1):

GUI tools like file management tools may hang or it may take ages just to look briefly into content if that folder is also remote (NAS, SAMBA). Of course, the application could better group files by date or something else less random.

Comment: Actually, this technique ensures a perfect distribution of files. So it's better than a date-based distribution, which might end up with large directory at peak days, and small directory at slow days.